# Fill the playbar with a different color in the player

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a small player to my site to listen to music. I found a beautiful example that I liked and want to change and finish it a little.

There is a track playback bar here:

```
<div id="seekbar">
  <input type="range" oninput="setPos(this.value)" id="seek" value="0" max="">
</div>
```

Now when the track is playing, a circle passes along this strip. And I also want to add that to the left of the circle, the passed strip was not the same color, but filled with white.

What do I need to do for this? Create another input that will only be filled with white, or can I do it all in one, which is better?

Here I want the strip to go like in the picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Et1.png

I add this stripe to html:

```
<div id="seekbar">
  <input type="range" oninput="setPos(this.value)" id="seek" value="0" max="">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

I style in css:

```
#myBar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

And I add movement to the script in the function `timeupdate`:

```
var progress = (song.currentTime/song.duration)*100;
document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = progress + "%";
```

Everything works, this strip appears and moves as it should, but I have it at the bottom of this main strip, but it should overlap it. You can see in the snippet.

How can this be fixed??

```js
var song = new Audio;
var isStopped = true;
var currentSong = 0;
var playlist = [];
var playlistVisible = false;
var randomTrack = false;

function skip(to) {
    if (to == 'prev') {
        stop();
        currentSong = (--currentSong)%playlist.length;
        if (currentSong < 0) {
            currentSong += playlist.length;
        }
        playpause();
    }
    else if (to == 'next') {
        stop();
        currentSong = (++currentSong)%playlist.length;
        playpause();
    }
}

function playpause() {
  if (!song.paused) {
        song.pause();
        document.getElementById("glow").classList.add("disable-animation");
    }
  else if (playlist.length == 0){
    togglePlaylist();
  }
    else {
      if (isStopped) {
            song.src = playlist[currentSong];
        }
        song.play();
        songFile = playlist[currentSong].split("/");
        songName = document.getElementById("songName");
        songName.innerHTML = songFile[songFile.length - 1].split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');
        document.getElementById("glow").classList.remove("disable-animation");
        isStopped = false;
    }
}

function random() {
  if (randomTrack) {
        document.getElementById('btn-random').classList.add("active");
        randomTrack = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('btn-random').classList.remove("active");
        randomTrack = true;
    }
}

function stop() {
    song.pause();
    document.getElementById("glow").classList.add("disable-animation");
    song.currentTime = 0;
    document.getElementById("seek").value = 0;
    isStopped = true;
    document.getElementById("songName").innerHTML = "playing track..";
}

function setPos(pos) {
    song.currentTime = pos;
}

function mute() {
    if (song.muted) {
        song.muted = false;
        document.getElementById('mute').className = "fa fa-volume-up";
    }
    else {
        song.muted = true;
        document.getElementById('mute').className = "fa fa-volume-off";
    }
}

function setVolume(volume) {
    song.volume = volume;
}

function togglePlaylist() {
    if (playlistVisible) {
        document.getElementById('playlist').className = "hide";
        document.getElementById('player').className = "";
        playlistVisible = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('player').className = "hide";
        document.getElementById('playlist').className = "";
        playlistVisible = true;
    }
}

function addList() {
    sourceUrl = document.getElementById('sourceUrl').value;
    sourceUrl.split(",").forEach((file) => {
        fileUrl = file.trim();
        if (fileUrl != "" && playlist.indexOf(fileUrl) == -1) {
            parent = document.getElementById('list');
            listItem = document.createElement('div');
            listItem.setAttribute('class','list-item');

            wrapper = document.createElement('div');
            wrapper.setAttribute('class','wrap-text');

            span = document.createElement('span');
      songFile = fileUrl.split("/");
            span.innerHTML = songFile[songFile.length - 1].split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');

            wrapper.appendChild(span);
            listItem.appendChild(wrapper);

            btn = document.createElement('button');
            btn.setAttribute('onclick','removeList(this)');
            btn.innerHTML = '&times;';

            listItem.appendChild(btn);
            parent.appendChild(listItem);
            playlist.push(fileUrl);
        }
    });
  document.getElementById('sourceUrl').value = '';
}

function removeList(item) {
    index = playlist.indexOf(item.parentElement.firstChild.innerText);
    if (index != -1){
        playlist.splice(index,1);
        item.parentElement.remove();
    }
}

song.addEventListener('error', function(){
    stop();
    document.getElementById("songName").innerHTML = "error loading audio";
});

song.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    curtime = parseInt(song.currentTime,10);
    document.getElementById('seek').max = song.duration;
    document.getElementById('seek').value = curtime;
});

song.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    song.pause();
    song.currentTime = 0;
    document.getElementById('seek').value = 0;
    if ((currentSong + 1) >= playlist.length) {
        currentSong = 0;    
    }
    else {
        currentSong++;
    }
    stop();
    song.src = playlist[currentSong];
    playpause();
});

var input = document.getElementById("sourceUrl");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        addList();
    }
});


// This area of code is only for preview purposes only

document.getElementById('sourceUrl').value = ["https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-summer.mp3",
"https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-anewbeginning.mp3",
"https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-littleidea.mp3",
"https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-cute.mp3",
"https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-memories.mp3"];
addList();
document.getElementById("glow").classList.remove("disable-animation");

// Code for preview ends here
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  background: #000000;
}
html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.glow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000, #262626);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.glow::before,
.glow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #ebc6df,
    #ebc6c9,
    #e1c6eb,
    #c6c9eb,
    #c6e8eb,
    #e373fb,
    #f787e6,
    #cb87f7,
    #87a9f7,
    #87f7ee
  );
  background-size: 400%;
  max-width: calc(300px + 4px);
  max-height: calc(300px + 4px);
  width: calc(300px + 4px);
  height: calc(300px + 4px);
  z-index: -1;
  animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.disable-animation::before,
.disable-animation::after {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.glow::after {
  filter: blur(28px);
}
#player,
#playlist {
  width: 243px;
  height: 212px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#songName {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.playlist-btn {
  width: 243px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
#list {
  height: 118px;
  max-height: 118px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #262626;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.list-item {
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.list-container button {
  width: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.add-list {
  padding: 4px 6px;
}
.wrap-text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 190px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#sourceUrl {
  background: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #1f1f1f;
  border-radius: 47px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  width: 192px;
}
#sourceUrl:active,
#sourceUrl:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0088ff;
}
.text {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
}
button {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000, #262626);
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  width: 55px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 32px;
}
button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0px #ffffff61;
}
button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px 0px #ffffff61;
}

#seek,
#volume {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #232323;
  outline: none;
}
#seek::-webkit-slider-thumb,
#volume::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#seek {
  display: block;
  width: 230px;
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  max-width: 5px;
  max-height: 5px;
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #333;
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #5c6670;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #232323;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 400% 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="container">
  <div id="glow" class="glow disable-animation">
    <div id="player">
      <span class="text">player</span>
      <br>
      <span id="songName" class="text">playing track..</span>
      <br>
      <div class="playback_controls">
        <button onclick="skip('prev')">
          <i class="fa fa-fast-backward"></i>
        </button>
        <button onclick="playpause()">
          <i class="fa fa-play"></i><i class="fa fa-pause"></i>
        </button>
        <button onclick="stop()">
          <i class="fa fa-stop"></i>
        </button>
        <button onclick="skip('next')">
          <i class="fa fa-fast-forward"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="seekbar">
        <input type="range" oninput="setPos(this.value)" id="seek" value="0" max="">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="volume_controls">
        <button onclick="mute()">
          <i id="mute" class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
        </button>
        <input type="range" id="volume" oninput="setVolume(this.value)" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="1">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="playlist" class="hide">
      <span class="text">playlist</span>
      <div class="list-container">

        <div id="list" class="scrollbar"></div>

        <div class="add-list">
          <input id="sourceUrl" type="text" placeholder="enter audio url" />
          <button onclick="addList()">+</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="playlist-btn">
      <button onclick="togglePlaylist()">
        <i id="playlist-btn" class="fa fa-list"></i>
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does this mean?  Now when the track is playing, a circle passes along this strip. And I also want to add that to the left of the circle, the passed strip was not the same color, but filled with white.  So what are you trying to do? can you show a picture of what you want?

Comment: @DCR I added a link to the photo in the post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 Video Player Progress Bar Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884899/html5-video-player-progress-bar-update)

Comment: @DCR I saw similar primekeys, but divs are used everywhere, do I have to redo everything myself, or can I work with this input?